# Define variable number of columns in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, series

I am new to pandas and I am creating new columns based on conditions from other existing columns using the following code:

```
df.loc[(df.item1_existing=='NO') & (df.item1_sold=='YES'),'unit_item1']=1
df.loc[(df.item2_existing=='NO') & (df.item2_sold=='YES'),'unit_item2']=1
df.loc[(df.item3_existing=='NO') & (df.item3_sold=='YES'),'unit_item3']=1
```

Basically, what this means is that if item is NOT existing ('NO') and the item IS sold ('YES') then give me a 1. This works to create 3 new columns but I am thinking there is a better way. As you can see, there is a repeated string in the name of the columns: '_existing' and '_sold'.  I am trying to create a for loop that will look for the name of the column that ends with that specific word and concatenate the beginning, something like this:

```
unit_cols = ['item1','item2','item3']
for i in unit_cols:
    df.loc[('df.'+i+'_existing'=='NO') & ('df'+i+'_sold'=='YES'),'unit_'+i]=1
```

but of course, it doesn't work. As I said, I am able to make it work with the initial example, but I would like to have fewer lines of code instead of repeating the same code because I need to create several columns this way, not just three. Is there a way to make this easier? is the for loop the best option?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Boolean series**, i.e. `True` / `False` depending on whether your condition is met. Coupled with [`pd.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) and f-strings ([PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), Python 3.6+), and using `__getitem__` (or its syntactic sugar `[]`) to allow string inputs, you can write your logic more readably:

```
unit_cols = ['item1','item2','item3']
for i in unit_cols:
    df[f'unit_{i}'] = df[f'{i}_existing'].eq('NO') & df[f'{i}_sold'].eq('YES')
```

If you need integers (`1` / `0`) instead of Boolean values, you can convert via `astype`:

```
    df[f'unit_{i}'] = df[f'unit_{i}'].astype(int)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I didn't know the existence of f strings.